# Installing nagios 4.1.1 on nginx on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: nginx, nagios

I am trying to install nagios on nginx.

I have done with Nagios core without any errors but when am trying to install plugins I am having errors

I am using "make" to do it & getting the below error:

```
libtool: link: gcc -DNP_VERSION=\"2.1.1\" -g -O2 -o check_dummy check_dummy.o  -L. libnpcommon.a ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a -lpthread -ldl
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/nagios/share/locale\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../lib -I../gl -I../intl -I/usr/include  -DNP_VERSION='"2.1.1"' -g -O2 -MT check_http.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/check_http.Tpo -c -o check_http.o check_http.c
mv -f .deps/check_http.Tpo .deps/check_http.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -DNP_VERSION='"2.1.1"' -g -O2  -L. -o check_http check_http.o libnpcommon.a ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a libnpcommon.a ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a  -lnsl -lresolv -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl
libtool: link: gcc -DNP_VERSION=\"2.1.1\" -g -O2 -o check_http check_http.o  -L. libnpcommon.a ../lib/libnagiosplug.a ../gl/libgnu.a -lnsl -lresolv -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl
libnpcommon.a(sslutils.o): In function `np_net_ssl_init_with_hostname_version_and_cert':
/usr/local/src/nagios-plugins-2.1.1/plugins/sslutils.c:73: undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [check_http] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/nagios-plugins-2.1.1/plugins'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/nagios-plugins-2.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So can anyone tell why am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This link is slove your problem
https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=36601&p=168235&hilit=SSLv3#p168235
Close your TOPIC